# Google Analytics: No stats from DMZ network segment

Tags: networking, firewall, dmz, google-analytics

We need to track hits on a particular page for usage stats, evaluate client need, etc. 
More specifically we need to track an internal DMZ network segment for hits on this page. Google Analytics displays traffic from other network segments but not this one.

Are there certain network configurations that would block Google stat collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're filtering HTTP outbound from the DMZ to the Internet, a proxy could be blocking Google Analytics traffic from that particular network, perhaps changing some of the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics merely uses requests to `www.google-analytics.com` to track statistics. You'll need to check firewall logs to see if outbound HTTP traffic to that domain are being blocked.